# win32con.WM_CHAR posts 虀 instead of intended keys

Tags: python, windows

I have a bit of python code that's supposed to paste a key to an already selected window in an autoclicker. Instead it pastes character 虀 during tests in notepad, no matter which virtual key code I use.

```
  def keystroke(self, hwnd):
    win32api.PostMessage(
        self.get_child_hwnd(hwnd), win32con.WM_CHAR, self.keyboard_key, 0)
```

Has anyone ever encountered such an issue? Googling shows nothing useful. I have python version 3.10.9

Using different keys, different windows, testing in sandbox, googling